# Can we specify the training and test document percentage in AWS comprehend Custom Entity Recognizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-comprehend

I trained a custom entity recognizer using AWS comprehend for an entity extraction problem. The trained recognizer uses default train and test data-split which here splits test data more than train data. This affects the recognizer metrics. Also these values(number of train & test documents) are higher than the total input "train.csv" file added in s3 bucket for training.
Total number of inputs given in csv file : 1010
Recognizer used train documents : 2480
Recognizer used test document : 3270

Comment: question is not pretty much clear.

Comment: @Navya I have the same issue. Seems like Comprehend is treating each line in the file as training documents. So, your 1010 documents might have multiple lines (2480+3270 = 5750). I am still puzzled 2480 train documents and 3270 test documents. Usually it is other way around, but seems like they are doing upside down!